# Twitter Bootstrap - navigation is not responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following mark up:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <ol class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">One</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Two</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Three</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Four</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Five</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Six</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Seven</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Eight</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Nine</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Ten</a>
                </li>                       
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine on my desktop, but once I start resizing the browser, the menu items just start to wrap. I expect it to turn into a vertical navigation. Am I doing something wrong?

I don't want to use the JavaScript solution, the one that makes a button appear, etc. I just want a simple CSS solution that doesn't require JS. I thought Bootstrap would handle this for me.

**UPDATE 1: What it looks like**

[image]

**UPDATE 2: What I want it to look like**

[image]

Comment: Please post your css as well to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Did you include the responsive css file?

Comment: @Caelea - I haven't written ANY css. I'm trying to let Bootstrap do as much as possible for me.

Comment: @RichBradshaw - yes, it's included. I downloaded the pre-packaged ZIP and am using those files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you're using the responsive meta tag at the top of the page, and follow any specific advice for anything else you're trying to do.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I'd also recommend looking at the Twitter Bootstrap site's code itself for extra guidance.

See: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

**Update**

Also make sure that on your nav-bar, you use the data-toggle and set the class appropriately:

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>

  <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
  <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

  <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
  <div class="nav-collapse">
    <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
  </div>

</div>
```

The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin and responsive Bootstrap CSS file.

See: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Comment: I have responsive meta tag and the responsive CSS. I'll try to take a screen show and post.

Comment: I don't want the data-toggle thing (as mentioned in my original post). I tried that and it kindda works. But I have 2 navs on the page and when I click on one button, both navs respond to it. Plus, I don't want to hide menu items and expose them by clicking a button. I just want it to become vertically stacked as the screen gets smaller.

Comment: If you want to have it appear the same way as you've provided in screenshot, and use the Bootstrap methods, this is how you'd do it. You could name the collapse div something different each time, and also what it does is it moves those items into that div, rather than show something completely different. Have a look at the code in http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html

Comment: Hi - maybe I can live with this approach for now. How do I implement multiple navbars? Which one is the collapse div? Is it the `div.nav-collapse`? Do I just change that to, say, `div.nav-collapse-1` and update `a[data-target]` to match?